# Stacking in data mining

Tags: machine-learning, classification

I have trained and tested the data using two classifiers such as naivebayes and SMO. Now I need to combine them using stacking.I need to know how I can perform stacking and what should be my base level classifier and meta level classifier.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like what you are want is [ensemble learning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ensemble_learning) rather than stacking. In an ensemble, you would use both classifiers to make decisions and combine those decisions.

Stacking is a process where the output of one level of classifiers is used as input for the next level. That is, the predictions of some classifiers are the features for other classifiers. For this, you would need to retrain one of the models with the outputs of the first classifier as input.

Which one of the classifiers should used where depends on your specific application. Similarly, how to do it depends on what system you've used to train these classifiers.

Answer (score 0):

To choose the base-level classifiers for stacking consider diverse classifiers that can potentially learn on a subset of features or a subset of data. For example, your base-level classifiers could be K-NN, Random Forest and Naive Bayes. For meta-level classifier we would like to choose a classifier that will learn well based on base-level predictions as features. A good candidate is Logistic Regression.

Using [mlxtend](https://github.com/rasbt/mlxtend) library as an example, we have:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB 
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from mlxtend.classifier import StackingClassifier

clf1 = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=1)
clf2 = RandomForestClassifier(random_state=1)
clf3 = GaussianNB()
lr = LogisticRegression()
sclf = StackingClassifier(classifiers=[clf1, clf2, clf3], 
                          meta_classifier=lr)
```

For examples on stacked classifiers and regressors see mlxtend [documentation page](http://rasbt.github.io/mlxtend/).